# want to get all tweets from a user which were sent after last fetch

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to pull (fetch) tweets of a particular user using twitter api 1.1 and php (abraham`s library).

Earlier I did this long ago when twitter had api 1.0  using since ID ...
i used to pull all recent tweets from a user.... parse it from most old  till the recent one... and used to save the id of latest one as since id in a file...
Then during next fetch, i used to provide that since id in query and then fetch all tweets which were sent only after that ID.

Somehow I lost the code and in 1.1 tutorials, I couldnt find use of since ID ...

I tried rewriting it as :

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => '@example', 'exclude_replies' => 'false', 'include_rts' => 'false', 'since_id' => $earlier_stored_since_id));
```

But its not giving proper results.
I mean it is giving results but those arre not in chronological order.... I want results in order oldest to newest so that in my foreach loop i can save id of last parsed tweet (which should be latest one from this fetch).

something like:

```
if(!empty($tweets)) {
foreach($tweets as $tweet) {

    # Access as an object
    $tweetText = $tweet->text;
    $sinceId= $tweet->id_str;
    echo '$sinceId is '.$sinceId;
    TwitterUtils::echoNewLine(0);

    # Make links active
    //$tweetText = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http:%2f%2f$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $tweetText);
//not activation of links working

    # Linkify user mentions
    //$tweetText = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href="http:/www.twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>", $tweetText);
    //linkifying not working

    # Linkify tags
    //$tweetText = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href="http:/search.twitter.com/search?q=$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>", $tweetText);
//linkifying tags not working

    # Output
    echo $tweetText;
    }
  file_put_contents($file_name_aditya, $sinceId);
  echo 'sinceId put in file is '.$sinceId;
  }
```

can anyone guide me where I am making a mistake?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with something similar in python and the only difference is that I save the '**greatest**' since_id as outlined on twitter dev [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines). Not depending on the tweets being received in a chronological order.

Comment: Thanks I found this useful.

Comment: Now I am storing all the IDs of tweets fetched in a php array and when all twweets are rpocessed, I am using max function to get max id from those array and then putting it in my file... using file_put_copntents